# iOS Component is automatically resizing but I don't know where and why

Tags: ios, objective-c, autoresizingmask

I am using [this control](https://github.com/robbdimitrov/RDVCalendarView) (RDVCalendarView) and I want to little customize it. I want to change height of calendar so it wouldn't be height as whole controller but little smaller. So in `loadView` I change code to this:

```
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
applicationFrame.size.height = 200;

_calendarView = [[RDVCalendarView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
[_calendarView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
[_calendarView setSeparatorStyle:RDVCalendarViewDayCellSeparatorTypeHorizontal];
[_calendarView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[_calendarView setDelegate:self];
self.view = _calendarView;
```

In whole `initWithFrame` method of `RDVCalendarView` there is correct size of height which I set. But after `viewWillAppear` there is `layoutSubviews` call and has 504 size of height. I don't know what happens but it looks like height is autoresizing to height of controller. I just don't know where it could be. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't directly set the frame of a UIViewController's main view, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html

Instead, you simply add the view you want to resize as a *subview* to your view controller's root view. To do that, simply change the method from `loadView` to `viewDidLoad`. At that point, the system has already created a default UIView for you and assigned it to the view controller's `view` property.

Change your code to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect calendarFrame = self.view.frame;
    calendarFrame.size.height = 200;

    _calendarView = [[RDVCalendarView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    [_calendarView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [_calendarView setSeparatorStyle:RDVCalendarViewDayCellSeparatorTypeHorizontal];
    [_calendarView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_calendarView setDelegate:self];

    [self.view addSubview:_calendarView];
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks you helped me. I know I should use method `addSubview` I just copy code from example and didn't notice that they make it this way.